# Spiceworks technology

Tags: spiceworks

Which technology was used to develop "spiceworks"? Somewhere I found that it was developed on RoR. But what is the back-end technology they use to store data?

Answer (score 1):

Spiceworks stores its information in a sqlite3 database file.

Here are some How-tos from the Spiceworks Community that talk about interesting ways to get at the data directly.

http://community.spiceworks.com/search?query=sqlite&tab=how_tos